# Why are the ID-masks and Ambient Occlusion outputs not pure white?

Tags: rendering, compositing-nodes, color, color-management

Whenever using ID-Masks (material and/or object) the result in the render output does not give me a solely black and white image.
The whites are slightly darker than they should be.
Even when overlaying an AO pass with a pure white color the result in the viewer/composite node is off-white.

Why is this?

**Some additional info:**
[image]

**Base render:**

[image: Base render]

**ID-Mask:**

[image: ID-Mask]

**Ambient Occlusion:**

[image: Ambient Occlusion]

**Blendfile:**

[image]

Comment: Maybe it is a result of Filmic mode

Comment: @SergeL I was thinking the same, but have no idea as to why this is happening.

Comment: Main concept of Filmic is unlimited dynamic range, so it can have "whiter than white" color. But it is scene-refered color. To make it visible on display, default 1.0 value is greyed to make room for "whiter than white" color (like 10.0). With default color mode 1.0 and 10.0 value will look identical on your screen.

Comment: @SergeL I understand...partially. Could you please elaborate your comment a bit more? Maybe post it as an answer and explain how to fix this?

Comment: Actually I don't know how to fix it, except saving all maps in EXR except "beauty" pass. EXR doesn't store color management transformation and this is what you want for the File Output node (I assume you will import masks in external app?). Try "half float" option if you are short on free space.